# com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError Warning: emptying DBPortPool to /IP:27017 b/c of error using spring MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, connection, driver

use org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate

it seems MongoDB Driver can't remove dropped socket from connection from pool until your code try use it

error as follow:

```
2013-9-2 9:13:16 com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError
警告: emptying DBPortPool to /IP:27017 b/c of error
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe(PoolOutputBuffer.java:129)
at com.mongodb.OutMessage.pipe(OutMessage.java:236)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:133)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
at     org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1530)
    at     org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1336)
```

Read operation to server /IP:27017 failed on database DB; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /IP:27017 failed on database DB

is there any other solution except try catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MongoDB Java driver can only tell a connection is dead when you start to use it - it doesn't periodically check connections (for example) to check they're still alive because doing this automatically could have a performance impact.  However, if you get an IOException in a single connection, all other connections will be closed and removed so new connections will be created afterwards.

It does mean that applications have a responsibility to catch Exceptions and perform a retry if appropriate.  Really your application is the best place to decide what to do in exceptional circumstances like connections disappearing.

Comment: thanks, I add an interceptor method before every action in my application, and which will call a connection to check if it is closed, thank you for your advise.

Comment: Thanks. I am puzzled, though, what other action would an application want to take other than reconnecting?

Comment: The application might want to NOT reconnect - there might be some serious problem with the network which means persistently trying to retry actually makes things worse, and/or you might want to send a message to the user saying the system is not available right now, come back later.  [Back pressure](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2012/05/apply-back-pressure-when-overloaded.html) is sometimes a better solution that blindly retrying and potentially making the situation worse.